# How to disallow push to docker repository

Tags: docker, repository, push

I am currently setting up a local cluster at my work using docker. Basically everything works fine, the only thing I worry about is, that other devs that use my setup may eventually push the local builds to a remote repository.

Since this would be a catastrophe because we are not allowed to upload the companies artefacts anywhere else than internal servers - is there a way to prevent other users from pushign to a remote docker repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> docker repo == docker registry?

Not sure I get the full picture about your desired workflow, but here are two options:

- Use registry [authentication](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/) and make sure that only authorised people push
- Configure networking / dns / hosts to resolve to the correct registry - e.g. `docker-registry.mycompany.com` resolves to the local registry for devs and to the remote registry for others.

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong terms. I want to avoid that anybody is able to push the local images which contain the company artefacts to any remote server/registry that is not in the companies trusted network.

Comment: I see. I think this might be a bit like asking *We are using git - how can I avoid developers pushing the company's source code to github*? As in: You can't. At least not with reasonable technical barriers.

Comment: yeah, you are right. Just want to make a bit harder to accidentally push somewhere else. As the 2 mentioned topics (authentication, dns) help to do so, I'll accept the answer.